# sampling points on a 2D grid with only one point on each intersection and keeping closeness

Tags: python, numpy, datagrid, nearest-neighbor, resampling

I'm working on a projet of labelling a seat plan (huge list of 2D coordinates) with an Excel spreadsheet.

I have a Python numpy array containing a list of 2D seat coordinates.
Theses 2D points are on a large scale (ie : -1000/-2000; -1500/1500) like on plot below
[image]

I would like to resample these points into a smaller grid in order to fit on an excel spreadsheet (something like width:200 and height:200)

- the smaller the grid is, the simpler it is to navigate on the spreadsheet
- we need only ONE single point in each intersection of this grid
- the original shape can be distorted if close points remains close (we want to keep the final plot readable)

I tried some resampling like screen below but i have no idea how to ensure there is not more than one points on each intersection of the final grid
[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "intersection"?

Comment: A "cell" of the grid